# python socket, how to receive all the message when buffer is not big enough?

Tags: python, sockets

```
# addition_server.py

import socket

buf_size = 4
host = ''
port = 8000
server_addr = (host, port)


def get_msg(soc):
    msg = ''
    while True:
        temp = soc.recv(buf_size)
        if not temp:
            break
        msg += temp
    return msg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
    soc.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    soc.bind(server_addr)
    soc.listen(0)

    runnnig = True
    while runnnig:
        client_soc, client_addr = soc.accept()
        print client_addr
        # socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
        message = client_soc.recv(buf_size)
        #message = get_msg(client_soc)
        if message == 'q':
            runnnig = False
        numbers = message.split(' ')
        numbers = filter(None, numbers)
        try:
            numbers = map(int, numbers)
            s = sum(numbers)
            numbers = map(str, numbers)
            answer = ' + '.join(numbers)
            answer = '%s = %s' % (answer, s)
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            answer = 'error'
        client_soc.sendall(answer)
        client_soc.close()
    soc.close()
```

---

```
# addition_client.py

import socket
from addition_server import get_msg
from addition_server import server_addr

buf_size = 1
runnnig = True
while runnnig:
    soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    soc.bind(('', 6060))  # without this, random port will be assigned
    soc.connect(server_addr)
    msg = raw_input('> ')
    if not msg:
        soc.close()
        break
    else:
        if msg == 'q':
            runnnig = False
    soc.sendall(msg)
    #reply = soc.recv(buf_size)
    # socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
    reply = get_msg(soc)
    print reply
    soc.close()
```

---

```
~/nuts/git/socket_learn/pairs$ python addition_client.py 
> 1 2
1 + 2 = 3
> 1 2 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "addition_client.py", line 23, in <module>
    reply = get_msg(soc)
  File "/home/phy/nuts/git/socket_learn/pairs/addition_server.py", line 14, in get_msg
    temp = soc.recv(buf_size)
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

---

The buffer size in the server is intentionally small, so the you can see the above error.
but the get_msg(client_soc) method not works in the server, I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The socket stream protocol implements a **stream** and there are no implicit message boundaries.

There is no way for the reader to know if a message is complete or not except if this is specified in the message content itself. No extra boundaries are added on the wire.

When you call `recv` and there is no data in the buffer the call will either raise an exception (non-blocking socket) or will just wait (blocking socket).

The `sendall` facility is just for avoiding writing a loop when sending a buffer but of course there is no way to implement `recvall` because there's no way to know when the message is complete.

You need to add a message boundary to your protocol; this could be a newline separating messages or prefixing each message with a message size. This way the reader will know when a message is complete before starting processing.

Comment: why on the client side, it can receive all the reply without specifying a boundary?

Comment: I get it. Because the server side closed.